# Can I root a 5 ft branch of ficus lyrata?

Tags: ficus, rooting-hormone

I have a large (10 ft +) fiddle leaf ficus in a pot; for 8 months it is outside and grows well. So when cold weather comes ( Global Warming is causing record cold in E TX again) I need to prune it to get back into the house . Internet sites show how to root leaves but not branches, I cut off 2 five foot branches this year, is it possible to root them ? I have tried previous years putting them in water and putting them in potting soil but without success.

Comment: You are unlikely to get lucky trying to root a woody part of a branch. Air layering might work, but would take a whole growing season so that won't help you now. A shorter cutting from the tip of a branch might work, but the standard method is to take leaf cuttings.

Comment: Agree with previous comment - use the leaves to take cuttings instead. 'Global warming' made me laugh when you're colder there ... yes, warming's happening, but it does  not mean everywhere gets warmer, it just means more extreme weather, one way or another. Climate change is probably a less confusing term...

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to get something a few feet tall to fill in the pot , as the leaves start about 4 ft up. And not need to start at ground level with a leaf.

Comment: The cold got some susanqua camellias in full bloom. Although some bushes had not yet bloomed.